# Найти все одинаковые элементы в двумерном массиве

Tags: java, массивы, поиск

Есть метод, который должен проверять, содержится ли число в двумерном массиве(по умолчанию имеющего `k` строк и `m` столбцов, начианащегося с 1 и линейно заполненного: 1, 2 , 3 ..., `k*m`). Если да, то метод выводит его индекс, в остальном [-1,-1]. Теперь добавляется метод, который должен создавать двумерный массив с рандомными числами от `low` до `high`(задаются при вызове функции создания рандомного массива). Задача все та же, нужно найти все элменты и если их несколько, то вывести их в массиве,однако мой код перестает искать, после того, как находит первое соответствие ( я понимаю почему он так делает, мне нужен совет, как сделать так, чтобы в случае, если чисел несколько, то они выводились не как один массив, а в несколько строчек, а в  лучшем случае по форме: `[x,y], [z,a],...`). 
P.S. переменная `pass` проверяет методом бинарного поиска(который содержит функция `find`), содержится ли число в массиве.

Comment: Бинарный поиск применим только к отсортированным данным.  Если нужно найти все элементы в двумерном массиве, заполненным случайным образом, бинарный поиск здесь не отработает корректно в общем случае.

Comment: Внутри циклов в операторе `if()` вместо `return arr;` сделать вывод в нужном виде.

Comment: @DmitryK, не будет это так работать, я уже пробовал, если бы все так было легко, то не было бы смысла задавать вопрос.

Comment: @NowhereMan, как можно в таком случае отсортировать двумерный массив, чтобы выдавало самое первое число?

Comment: Вообще-то это действительно легко - уберите `find()`. Просто сравнивайте каждый элемент массива с искомым числом и если совпало - выводите индексы `if (haystack[i][j] == needle){}`. На сортировку затратится больше времени, чем 1 проход по всему массиву.

Comment: @DmitryK, к сожелению, тестовая среда, как и само задание, завязаны на бинарный поиск..

Comment: А зачем вам сортировка для выдачи самого первого числа??  Проще перебирать по очереди (O(N)), чем отсортировать и искать бинарным поиском (O(N log N)).

Comment: В условии задачи, которую вы привели, нет ни слова о бинарном поиске. " тестовая среда, как и само задание, завязаны на бинарный поиск" - в таком случае, сортировка массива должна быть до вызова этой функции. Т.е. массив должен передаваться в уже отсортированном виде. А вы пишете, что он заполнен рандомными числами. Если массив уже отсортирован, то в цикле по строкам делаете `find()` для каждой строки массива как для одномерного массива. Если нашли искомый элемент, то все остальные идут за ним - просто выводите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализация метода, который возвращает индексы всех элементов, равных заданному, в двумерном массиве (зубчатом) при помощи Stream API:

```java
public static int[][] search2D(int[][] haystack, int needle) {
    return IntStream.range(0, haystack.length)                // индексы строк
        .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, haystack[i].length) // индексы колонок
            .filter(j -> haystack[i][j] == needle) // поиск элементов
            .mapToObj(j -> new int[]{i, j})        // создать массив для пары индексов
        ) // Stream<Stream<int[]>>
        .flatMap(s -> s) // Stream<int[]>
        .toArray(int[][]::new);            // получить 2D массив индексов
}
```

Тест:

```java
int[][] arr = {
  {1, 2, 3, 4},
  {6, 8, 4, 2, 0, 2},
  {2, 0, 2, 1, 2}
};

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(search2D(arr, 2)));
```

Результат:

```
[[0, 1], [1, 3], [1, 5], [2, 0], [2, 2], [2, 4]]
```